# Grunt: How do I run seperate processes for CSS (sass, concat, minify) and JS (concat, minify)

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I'm looking at the grunt watch documentation but I can see how to run a separate process for my javascript files. Below is what I have for CSS:

GruntFile.js

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        // running `grunt sass` will compile once
        sass: {
            dist: {
                options: {
                    style: 'expanded'
                },
                files: {
                    './public/css/sass_styles.css': './src/sass/sass_styles.scss' // 'destination': 'source'
                }
            }
        },
        // bring in additonal files that are not part of the sass styles set
        concat: {
            dist: {
                src: [
                    'public/css/datepicker.css', 
                    'public/css/jquery.tagsinput.css', 
                    'public/css/sass_styles.css', 
                    'application/themes/japantravel/style.css'
                ],
                dest: 'public/css/all.css',
            },
        },
        // running `grunt cssmin` will minify code to *.min.css file(s)
        cssmin: {
            minify: {                                 
                expand: true,
                cwd: "public/css/",
                src: ["all.css", "!*.min.css"],
                dest: "public/css/",
                ext: ".min.css"
            }
        },
        // running `grunt watch` will watch for changes
        watch: {
            files: ["./src/sass/*.scss", "./src/sass/partials/*.scss"],
            tasks: ["sass", "concat", "cssmin"]
        }
    });

    // load tasks
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-cssmin");
    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-watch");
};
```

As you can see I have tasks for CSS ["sass", "concat", "cssmin"], but I want to do separate tasks for separate files (js) - concat and minify - and listen for changes (watch). Can someone point me in the correct direction, I'm not really sure what I should be searching for. Is this something that watch can handle, or is there another plugin? I'm a little new to grunt so still trying to figure out how to use it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use '**grunt-concurrent**' for that, you can define multiple tasks with it. In combination with watch sets you will have the proper solution. https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-concurrent

```
# to install:
npm install grunt-concurrent --save-dev
```

And this will be your adjusted function then.
**Remember, you still have to set some uglify and jshint properties!** But I believe that's not the issue here.

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({

        /* .. */

        // running `grunt watch` will watch for changes
        watch: {
            // Use 'sets' like this, just make up a name for it:
            watchCss: {
                files: ["./src/sass/*.scss", "./src/sass/partials/*.scss"], // Directory to look for changes
                tasks: ["concurrent:taskCss"] // Tasks you want to run when CSS changes
            },
            watchJs: {
                files: ["./src/js/**/*.js"], // Directory to look for changes
                tasks: ["concurrent:taskJs"] // Tasks you want to run when JS changes
            }
        },
        concurrent: {
            taskCss: ["sass", "concat", "cssmin"],  // define the CSS tasks here
            taskJs:  ["jshint", "concat", "uglify"] // define the JS tasks here
        },
    });

    // load tasks
    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-sass");
    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-concat");
    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-cssmin");
    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-watch");
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint'); // Added
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify'); // Added
    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-concurrent"); // Added

    // register tasks (note: you can execute sets from concurrent)
    grunt.registerTask('default', ["concurrent:taskCss", "concurrent:taskJs"]);
    grunt.registerTask('css', ["concurrent:taskCss"]);
    grunt.registerTask('js', ["concurrent:taskJs"]);
};
```

To watch for changes:

```
grunt watch
# if a css file is changed, only the css tasks are performed
```

You can also execute a task from the prompt directly, for example:

```
grunt js
# This will only execute the registered task 'js'
# In this case that task points to 'concurrent:taskJs' wich will run jshint, concat and uglify
```

To install uglify and jshint:
https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify
https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jshint

```
npm install grunt-contrib-uglify --save-dev
npm install grunt-contrib-jshint --save-dev
```